# How to use component from another form

Tags: java, forms, jframe

I am using Java Swing and I have 2 classes. A.class and B.class. B.class is purely a JFrame form with a simple textarea. A.class is the main class and I wish to call B.class from A.class. I know I can show the B form using setvisible, but I can I access the textarea in B to input some text?

```
 B myObj = new B();
 myObj.setVisible(true);
 myObj.jTextArea1.settext("......") ; // doesn't work
```

thanks

Comment: The normal way to do this is to save the TextArea someplace, then provide a method to access that TextArea.  Note that [Swing is not thread safe.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: bObject.getTextArea();  // GETTER METHOD that returns the textArea object